# Embeded Mongodb to Spring Boot always recreate database

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I need to embed Mongodb to Spring Boot application. But the way how I've done
it leads to re-creating mongo db every time I start app. I mean, my documents don't save to database persistently.

Every start I see in logs:

```
2017-11-22 12:03:49.188  INFO 10464 --- [           main] c.j.s.embedmongo.EmbeddedMongoBuilder    : Initializing embedded MongoDB instance
2017-11-22 12:03:49.215  INFO 10464 --- [           main] d.f.embed.process.store.Downloader       : Extract C:\Users\lev\.embedmongo\win32\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-3.2.1.zip : starting...
2017-11-22 12:03:49.483  INFO 10464 --- [           main] d.f.embed.process.store.Downloader       : Extract C:\Users\lev\.embedmongo\win32\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-3.2.1.zip : extract mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-3.2.1/bin/mongod.exe
2017-11-22 12:03:49.484  INFO 10464 --- [           main] d.f.embed.process.store.Downloader       : Extract C:\Users\lev\.embedmongo\win32\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-3.2.1.zip : noting left
2017-11-22 12:03:49.484  INFO 10464 --- [           main] d.f.embed.process.store.Downloader       : Extract C:\Users\lev\.embedmongo\win32\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-3.2.1.zip : finished
2017-11-22 12:03:49.484  INFO 10464 --- [           main] c.j.s.embedmongo.EmbeddedMongoBuilder    : Starting embedded MongoDB instance
2017-11-22 12:03:51.180  INFO 10464 --- [           main] d.f.embed.process.runtime.Executable     : start de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfigBuilder$ImmutableMongodConfig@867ba60
2017-11-22 12:03:51.383  INFO 10464 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:3707], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2017-11-22 12:03:51.418  INFO 10464 --- [-localhost:3707] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:1}] to localhost:3707
2017-11-22 12:03:51.419  INFO 10464 --- [-localhost:3707] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:3707, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=432755}
2017-11-22 12:03:51.509  INFO 10464 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:2}] to localhost:3707
2017-11-22 12:03:51.939  WARN 10464 --- [           main] o.s.d.m.c.m.BasicMongoPersistentProperty : Customizing field name for id property not allowed! Custom name will not be considered!
```

Probably this part leads to database overwriting:
Downloader       : Extract C:\Users\lev.embedmongo\win32\mongodb-win32

My Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-mongodb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot and Mongo DB</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Controller for storing document:

```
@RequestMapping("/check")
@ResponseBody
public List<Domain> check(){
    System.out.println("/check");
    Domain domain = new Domain(i++, "Check_"+String.valueOf(i), true); 
    dm.save(domain);
    return dm.findAll();
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface DomainRepository extends MongoRepository<Domain, Long> {

    Domain findFirstByDomain(String domain);

    Domain findByDomainAndDisplayAds(String domain, boolean displayAds);

    //Supports native JSON query string
    @Query("{domain:'?0'}")
    Domain findCustomByDomain(String domain);

    @Query("{domain: { $regex: ?0 } })")
    List<Domain> findCustomByRegExDomain(String domain);

}
```

appilcation.properties:

```
server.port = 8091
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
spring.data.mongodb.database=testme
```

How can I solve this isssue?

Comment: Please add this comment as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's `embedded`, every time application is started the DB will be re-created as previous one has been deleted when the app was stopped.